# Simplified Windows' tracert command

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I wrote a simplified versions of Windows' [`tracert`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tracert) command as an exercise and to learn about TTL in packets. It shows the path that your internet traffic will (likely) take on the way to the given destination.

Here's an example (some stuff is redacted out of paranoia):

[image]

```
python tracert.py google.com -h
usage: tracert.py [-h] [-d] [-o O] [-w W] [-t T] ip

positional arguments:
  ip

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -d          Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
  -o O        Maximum number of hops to search for target.
  -w W        Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
  -t T        How many per packets to send per hop.
```

Unfortunately, due to using Scapy, the timings seem to be somewhat broken. Sending packets seems to have an inherent overhead, and that overhead dwarfs the actual time. Unless Scapy provides a way to access round-trip times though, I don't think I can fix that without doing away with Scapy and doing the packet construction/sending manually. I mention this since anyone familiar with `tracert` will likely find the pattern of times odd. They were included mostly as a "semi-functional" placeholder so I could try to implement the incremental behavior of `tracert`.

I tried to match a lot of `tracert`s behavior, but I didn't go overboard. I opted to have the target first instead of last for simplicity.

The hardest part was getting displaying incremental as they came in to match `tracert`. I went through several redesigns of `_tracert_hop_row` where I tried to return an iterable of results, and the consumer could print results as they were produced. This ended up being a mess though, because I also needed to communicate back whether we had found the destination yet. I ended up printing the result directly instead.

My main concern is `_tracert_hop_row`. It's a mess, and it's long. Any tips regarding it or anything else would be appreciated.

`reverse_dns.py`

```
from typing import Union

from scapy.layers.inet import UDP, IP
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSQR, DNSRR
from scapy.sendrecv import sr1


_REVERSE_DOMAIN = ".in-addr.arpa"
_OCTET_DELIMITER = "."


def _reverse_dns_packet(ip: str, dns_server: str) -> DNS:
    reversed_ip = _OCTET_DELIMITER.join(reversed(ip.split(_OCTET_DELIMITER)))
    question = DNSQR(qname=f"{reversed_ip}{_REVERSE_DOMAIN}", qtype=12)
    return IP(dst=dns_server) / UDP(dport=53) / DNS(qd=question)


def reverse_dns_lookup(ip: str, dns_server: str, **sr1_kwargs) -> Union[None, int, str]:
    """
    Returns the str host-name if it could be resolved,
      or an int response code if there was an error,
      or None if the DNS server couldn't be reached.
    Unless you know the DNS server will be reachable, setting a timeout via the kwargs is advised.
    """
    request = _reverse_dns_packet(ip, dns_server)
    resp = sr1(request, **sr1_kwargs)
    if resp is None:
        return None
    resp_code = resp[1][DNS].rcode
    if resp_code == 0:
        raw = resp[1][DNSRR].rdata
        return raw.decode("UTF-8")
    else:
        return resp_code
```

`tracert.py`

```
from typing import Tuple, List, Optional, Callable, TypeVar
from collections import Counter
from time import perf_counter
import argparse as ap

from scapy.config import conf
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, ICMP
from scapy.sendrecv import sr1

from reverse_dns import reverse_dns_lookup


_MAX_TTL = 255
_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5
_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY = False
_DEFAULT_TESTS_PER = 3
_DEFAULT_RESOLVE_HOSTNAMES = True
_TABLE_SPACING = 10

NO_INFO_SYM = "*"

T = TypeVar("T")


def _new_trace_packet(destination_ip: str, hop_n: int) -> ICMP:
    return IP(dst=destination_ip, ttl=hop_n) / ICMP()


# Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845191/3000206
def get_gateway_of(ip: str) -> str:
    return conf.route.route(ip)[2]


def _check_hop_n(destination_ip: str, hop_n: int, **sr1_kwargs) -> Optional[Tuple[str, bool]]:
    """
    Returns a tuple of (hop_ip, destination_reached?)
    """
    sr1_kwargs.setdefault("timeout", _DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
    sr1_kwargs.setdefault("verbose", _DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)

    packet = _new_trace_packet(destination_ip, hop_n)
    reply = sr1(packet, **sr1_kwargs)
    return reply and (reply[IP].src, reply[ICMP].type == 0)


def _find_proper_route(replies: List[ICMP]) -> Optional[Tuple[str, bool]]:
    if not replies:
        return None
    ip_isfin_pairs = [(resp[IP].src, resp[ICMP].type == 0) for resp in replies]
    found_destination = next((ip for ip, isfin in ip_isfin_pairs if isfin), None)
    selected_ip = found_destination or Counter(ip for ip, _ in ip_isfin_pairs).most_common(1)[0][0]
    return selected_ip, bool(found_destination)


def _time_exec(f: Callable[[], T]) -> Tuple[float, T]:
    """
    Executes the function and returns a tuple of [exec_seconds, result].
    """
    start = perf_counter()
    result = f()
    end = perf_counter()
    return end - start, result


def _cell_print(x: str) -> None:
    print(x.ljust(_TABLE_SPACING), end="", flush=True)


def _tracert_hop_row(destination_ip: str,
                     n_tests: int,
                     hop_n: int,
                     resolve_hostname: bool,
                     **sr_kwargs) -> bool:
    sr_kwargs.setdefault("timeout", _DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
    sr_kwargs.setdefault("verbose", _DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)
    packet = _new_trace_packet(destination_ip, hop_n)
    replies = []
    for _ in range(n_tests):
        secs, reply = _time_exec(lambda: sr1(packet, **sr_kwargs))
        _cell_print(NO_INFO_SYM if reply is None else f"{int(secs * 1000)} ms")
        if reply:
            replies.append(reply)
    if not replies:
        _cell_print(NO_INFO_SYM)
        return False
    best_route, found_destination = _find_proper_route(replies)
    if resolve_hostname:
        host = reverse_dns_lookup(best_route, get_gateway_of(best_route), **sr_kwargs)
        if isinstance(host, str):
            _cell_print(f"{host} [{best_route}]")
        else:
            _cell_print(best_route)
    else:
        _cell_print(best_route)
    return found_destination


def tracert_internal(destination_ip: str,
                     n_tests_per_hop: int = _DEFAULT_TESTS_PER,
                     resolve_hostnames: bool = _DEFAULT_RESOLVE_HOSTNAMES,
                     max_hops: int = _MAX_TTL,
                     **sr_kwargs) -> None:
    for hop_n in range(1, max_hops + 1):
        _cell_print(str(hop_n))
        found_destination = _tracert_hop_row(destination_ip, n_tests_per_hop, hop_n, resolve_hostnames, **sr_kwargs)
        print()
        if found_destination:
            break


def main():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("ip")
    parser.add_argument("-d", action="store_false", default=True,
                        help="Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.")
    parser.add_argument("-o", type=int, default=_MAX_TTL,
                        help="Maximum number of hops to search for target.")
    parser.add_argument("-w", type=float, default=_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                        help="Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.")
    parser.add_argument("-t", type=int, default=_DEFAULT_TESTS_PER,
                        help="How many per packets to send per hop.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        tracert_internal(args.ip, args.t, args.d, args.o, timeout=args.w)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is the Scapy issues acceptable? Are you asking for help with it?

Comment: @Peilonrayz The code works, the times are just not very accurate. I only included them to match the incremental behavior of the actual program. They weren't the focus of this program. No, I don't want the timing inflation dealt with here. I just included the comment since anyone who uses `tracert` would probably notice the odd time pattern.

Comment: Ok, that seems fine for me. Our short exchange should keep your question from being closed.

Comment: Make sure you are using 2.4.4. It fixed most of the issues with packet timestamps

Comment: @Cukic0d Thanks. That's what I'm currently using though. I think it's just the overhead of the library, and other stuff like the fact that I'm wrapping the code in a lambda before timing. Timing the entirety of the `sr1` is probably not great since `sr1` seems to be doing quite a lot behind the scenes.

Comment: oh wait you're doing it wrong. use `answer.time - request.sent_time` and it will be much more accurate

Comment: @Cukic0d Oh, cool, thanks. I had no idea it provided that information. I wouldn't have guessed that it would mutate `request` with the time. Thanks. That definitely helps.

Comment: @Cukic0d You were right. The timings now roughly match what `tracert` reports. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if resolve_hostname:
    host = reverse_dns_lookup(best_route, get_gateway_of(best_route), **sr_kwargs)
    if isinstance(host, str):
        _cell_print(f"{host} [{best_route}]")
    else:
        _cell_print(best_route)
else:
    _cell_print(best_route)
```

You are doing `_cell_print` and using `best_route` in each case, which is also the default value. It might be motivated to use a different structure here, such as

````
output = best_route  #default value
if resolve_hostname:
    host = reversee_dns_lookup(best_route, get_gateway_of(best_route), **sr_kwargs)
    if isinstance(host, str):
        output = f"{host} [{best_route}]"

_cell_print(output)

```
````

Comment: Thanks, I had a thinking freeze while trying to figure out a better way to write that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Cukic0d's suggestion, the timing can be easily improved by making use of the `.time` and `.sent_time` attributes of the packets.

I removed `_time_exec`, and rejigged the `for` loop to be just:

```
for _ in range(n_tests):
    reply = sr1(packet, **sr_kwargs)
    if reply is None:
        _cell_print(NO_INFO_SYM)
    else:
        _cell_print(f"{int((reply.time - packet.sent_time) * 1000)} ms")
        replies.append(reply)
```

The timings now roughly match that of `tracert`.